# EditorFor with Collections and Name attribute

Tags: model-view-controller, templates

I am trying to create a form that allows the editing of multiple rows of data. I have no problem looping through and getting input boxes to render...I just cannot get the name attributes to output correctly.

I know that in order to submit a collection you need to post back an indexed name where the index is sequential starting at 0.

```
<input name="Books[0].Title" />
<input name="Books[1].Title" />
and so on...
```

Now, I can get the EditorFor function to output my proper name with given the following loop code

```
@For n = 0 To (Model.Books.Count - 1)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) Model.Books.Item(n).Title)
Next
```

giving me

```
<input name="Books[0].Title" />
<input name="Books[1].Title" />
and so on...
```

My problem is VS shows the following warning

*Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable.*

Yet when I change the loop to

```
@For n = 0 To (Model.Books.Count - 1)
    Dim item = Mode.Books.Item(n)

    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) item.Title)
Next
```

I get

```
<input name="$VB$Local_item.Title" />
<input name="$VB$Local_item.Title" />
and so on...
```

Any thoughts? Should I just ignore the warning?

Thanks.

- Jason

Answer (score 0):

MVC works by actually breaking apart the lambda expression, and seeing what it's made of.  It doesn't just execute the lambda and get the result.  So you need to actually use the model parameter in the lambda for it to work.  This should do it for you:

```
@For n = 0 To (Model.Books.Count - 1)
    Dim index = n

    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m(index).Title)
Next
```